# GCP Functions Framework for Python - Necessary to include in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

When creating a function to run on GCP Cloud Functions, do you need to include the [functions framework for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) as a requirement in your `requirements.txt` file?

The [official repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) suggests that you don't:

> On Cloud Functions, using the Functions Framework is not necessary:
> you don't need to add it to your requirements.txt file.

But the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing) suggests that you do:

> Your requirements.txt file must include the Functions Framework for
> Python as a dependency